# Как записать в указатель адрес другого указателя?

Tags: c, указатели, c99

Есть тип данных object. Основная идея, что он не простой, больше, чем указатель.

```
typedef struct _obj {
    // что-то на 40 бит
} object;
```

массив `object* a = malloc(sizeof(object) * n);`, где n - кол-во элементов.

Как организовать массив так, чтобы `a[i]` хранил ссылку/адрес/указатель на `a[i+1]`?

Comment: Вы хотите в `a` записать что? Адрес *переменной* `b`? Но какой в этом смысл? это потребует для работы сплошных приведений типа... Записать в `a` адрес, хранящийся в `b`? тривиальным присваиванием...

Comment: Хочу сделать pool allocator. В свободном эллементе должен храниться адрес на следующий свободный.

Comment: Ну у вас же есть для этого поле `next`? храните в нем...

Comment: У этого поля другой смысл. Дописал вопрос.

Comment: Гляньте тут, это реализация linkedList - листалка, https://github.com/ClnViewer/LinkedHashMap/blob/35955245f42277de68226093aec2d017639fc1fa/src/hashmap-link-hash.c#L284 . И Юнион с int выглядит странно в вашем коде, какое назначение int ?

Comment: Как всегда, с помощью приведений типа (cast). И лучше на пишете вы эти typedef-ы, без них картина яснее (согласен, букв больше...)

Comment: Убрал все лишнее из вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю в чем проблема.

```
typedef struct _obj 
{
  struct _obj *next;
  /* ... */
} object;
...

object* a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);

for (unsigned i = 0; i + 1 < n; ++i)
  a[i].next = &a[i + 1];

a[n - 1].next = NULL;
```

Готово.

Однако не ясно, при чем здесь "записать в указатель адрес другого указателя".